# Dynamically reduce width of a section when reducing browser window size

Tags: html, css

I have a section of a html wtith these characteristics:

```
section {
background:blanchedalmond;
width: 50%;
height: 75%;
margin: 200px auto 0;
margin-top: 50px;
font-family: 'Courier New';
line-height: 150%;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: justify;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Basically, I need to reduce the blank spaces outside section gradually as I reduce the size of the window and only start reducing the size of "section" when there is no blank space left:

[image]

Comment: you are overthinking this. You simply need `max-width:Xpx:margin:auto` to your element and define X like you want. Remove everything else

Answer (score 1):

you can try with transition

```
section {
    background: blanchedalmond;
    width: 50%;
    height: 75%;
    margin: 200px auto 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-family: 'Courier New';
    line-height: 150%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
  }

@media (max-width: 768px) {
       section {
         width: 100%;
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to adjust `width` of container if we know that width of screen is changed. So to figure out that width of screen is changed, we need to apply media query or use JavaScript.

It would look like this with media query:

```
@media (max-width: 620px) {
  section {
      width: 100%;
  }
}
```

An example:

```css
section {
  background: blanchedalmond;
  width: 50%;
  height: 75%;
  margin: 200px auto 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  line-height: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <section>
    1
  </section>
```

**UPDATE:**

With JavaScript it would like this:

```js
const halfScreen = `50%`;

const onBodyResize = () => {
    let fooSection = document.getElementById("fooSection");
    let fooSectionClientWidth = fooSection.clientWidth;
    let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

    if (windowWidth < 500 &&
        fooSectionClientWidth < windowWidth) {
        fooSection.style.width = `${fooSectionClientWidth + 1}px`;
        //console.log(`2 fooSection.style.width`, fooSection.clientWidth);
    }
    else if (fooSectionClientWidth >= windowWidth  ){
        fooSection.style.width = `${windowWidth}px`;
    }
    else {
        fooSection.style.width = halfScreen;
    }
}


const onLoad = () => {
    let fooSection = document.getElementById("fooSection");
    fooSection.style.width = halfScreen;
}
```

```css
*, html, body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  background: blanchedalmond;
  height: 75%;
  margin: 200px auto 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  line-height: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<body onload="onLoad()"  onresize="onBodyResize()">
    <section id="fooSection">
      1
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: It sort of work. However, the change in size of "section" is not gradual. Basically, I need to reduce the blank spaces outside section gradually as I reduce the size of the window and only start reducing the size of "section" when there is no blank space left.

Comment: @Manuel I've added a JavaScript example. Please, see my updated answer. But i am also curious to see pure CSS solution.